# Macros, htlatex with/without "xhtml, mathml"

Tags: tex4ht

Following mwe.tex works with `htlatex mwe.tex`. With `htlatex mwe.tex "xhtml, mathml"` it gives correct C_5 but `\S` is like S5, not S_5.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xspace}
\renewcommand*{\S}{\ensuremath{S_5}\xspace}

\begin{document}

Group $C_5$ is subgroup of \S.

\end{document}
```

Too many things to tweak with htlatex... For example `"xhtml, mathml"` fixed problem that I asked two days ago.

Comment: Why don't you leave out the `\ensuremath` and use `\S` in math mode? However, it seems that the `mathml` option isn't able to see the subscript in the macro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sub- and super-scripts are redefined on several places by `tex4ht`. `\S` command doesn't work because in the document preamble they have different meaning than in the document text. If you want to activate them, use command line option `early_` for subscripts and `early^` for superscripts. So in your case, compile the document with:

```
htlatex filename "xhtml, mathml, early_"
```

for info about more command line options, see [this page](http://www.cvr.cc/?p=504). On that blog, there are more [interesting articles](http://www.cvr.cc/?cat=14), if you are interested in more advanced usage of tex4ht.